# Flow emits different values when collecting it multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow, kotlin-sharedflow

I created a Flow from which I emit data. When I collect this flow twice, there are 2 different sets of data emitted from the same variable instead of emitting the same values to both collectors.

I have a simple Flow that I created myself. The text will be logged twice a second

```
    val demoFlow: Flow<String> = flow {
        while (true) {
            val text = "Flow ${(0..100).random()}"
            Log.d("TAG", text)
            emit(text)
            delay(1000)
        }
    }
```

In my viewModel I have a simple function that gets the previous Flow

```
fun getSimpleFlow() = FlowRepository.demoFlow
```

And in my Fragment I collect and display my Flow

```
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                launch {
                    viewModel.getSimpleFlow().collect {
                        binding.tv1.text = it
                    }
                }
                launch {
                    viewModel.getSimpleFlow().collect {
                        binding.tv2.text = it
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If I transform the Flow to a StateFlow or a SharedFlow, I no longer have this problem.
I don't understand how or why this happens since I'm using the same 'demoFlow' variable.
Is there a way to get the same values from 'demoFlow' without converting to a StateFlow or a SharedFlow?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted what value do you get in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular `Flow`s are cold, this behaviour is by design.

The `demoFlow` is the same, so you have the same `Flow` instance. However, collecting the flow multiple times actually runs the body inside the `flow { ... }` definition every time from the start. Each independent collection has its own variable `i` etc.

Using a `StateFlow` or a `SharedFlow` allows to share the source of the flow between multiple collectors. If you use `shareIn` or `stateIn` on some source flow, that source flow is only collected once, and the items collected from this source flow are shared and sent to every collector of the resulting state/shared flow. This is why it behaves differently.

In short, reusing a `Flow` instance is not sufficient to share the collection. You need to use flow types that are specifically designed for this.